# Where should I put @Qualifier when I have two @Beans?

Tags: java, spring, redis, javabeans

So I have two beans for redis connection, and I am trying to specify certain times to use redisB. If I am correct, I need to put @Qualifier("redisB") somewhere, but I am not sure where to put it.

First bean

```
@Bean("default")
@Primary
public LettuceConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory(){
...
}
```

Second bean

```
@Bean("redisB")
public LettuceConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory(final RedisProperties redisProperties){
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The @Qualifier Annotation is used to remove ambiguity during INJECTION of two beans of the same class type. So I'm not very familiar with setting up a redis connection, but the @Qualifier Annotation would be used when the bean is injected, not in the code you have shown where the beans are declared.

For example if another object, like a RedisTemplate required a redisConnectionFactory in its constructor and you wanted to specify which of the to redisConnectionFactoryBeans to use it would look like this.

```
@Bean("redisBTemplate")
public StringRedisTemplate stringRedisTemplate(@Qualifier("redisB") LettuceConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {
 return new StringRedisTemplate(redisConnectionFactory);
}
```

This is one example how you would use it to inject it into another bean, but you would use @Qualifier anytime you want to inject one of those connectionFactory beans to specify which one you want to inject. It would not be used during bean declaration.